How to fix Mathematica's interpretation of numbers
I am trying to code something where the result are integers. However I am not sure how Mathematica interprets the number (3-2.95)/0.05 , since If I ask Mathematica to give me the integer part of this number it returns 0. However if I ask of (3-2.9)/0.05 it now gives 2.
Therefore I am bit confused how I can tell Mathematica to work with the integer number itself. This gives me trouble since I want to define a matrix using this (3-2.95)/0.05 which is supposed to be 1 , Mathematica just returns me an empty matrix since it does not interpret this as one, and if I ask for the integer part of the number this doesn't solve my issue.
Does anyone know how I can fix this ?
dimEa[a_, h_] := 
 If[0 <= a <= 1, a/h, 
  If[1 <= a <= 2, 1/h, (3 - a)/h]]

Here 's an example of the code.
If I do IntegerPart[dimEa[0.05, 0.05]]I get the correct result $1$. However if I do IntegerPart[dimEa[2.95, 0.05]] I get 0. I am not sure how to fix this.

Use Round instead of IntegerPart.

Thanks that does indeed fix it.

IntegerPart takes the digits to the left of the decimal point. The result of dimEa[2.95, 0.05] is actually 0.9999999999999964, so IntegerPart returns 0.

Or (3 - 2.95)/0.05 // Rationalize

Gernerally, if you dont want machine precision numbers in a fomula use rationals. Rationals, Complex and complex rationals are a numeric type coded as pairs  of Real or Rational numbers.
Exp[31/3 + I 7/5] // FullForm
Power[E,Complex[Rational[31,3],Rational[7,5]]]
Round[Exp[31/3 + I 7/5] , 1/100]
$$\frac{261243}{50}+\frac{3029313 i}{100}$$
N[Exp[31/3 + I 7/5], 43]

5224.85954777777128374132629792444722832581 + 
30293.12808774603513044776830572728877321066 I

